# Prove that $\lim_{x\to {\pi}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}} = 1$

Tags: limits, function-and-relation-composition

How can I prove
 $\lim_{x\to {\pi}}\sin{\frac{x}{2}} = 1$ 
In my book it is said that this can be proved directly from the functions composition limits sentence, Which is defined using those steps:

define $g(x), f(x)$ such that:

1. The following limit exists:
   $L = \lim_{x\to {x_0}}f(x)$
2. $x_0 = \lim_{t\to {t_0}}g(x)$
3. There is a nominal environment in which $g(t) \neq x_0$

If the above 3 conditions apply, than it is known that:

$\lim_{t\to {t_0}}f(g(t)) = L$

Edit:
I understand this can later on be proved easily, yet I'm still not allowed to use the continuous property

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you mean by "using function composition"?  Do you have an example of this?

Comment: if you are not allowed to use the continuous function or composite function property, then I don't think you have any other way to prove it except by definition.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\lim_{x \to \pi} x/2 = \pi/2 $. Since $\sin x $ is continuous at $x = \pi $, then

$$ \lim_{x \to \pi } \sin \left( \frac{ x }{2} \right ) = \sin \left( \lim_{x \to \pi } \frac{ x }{2} \right) = \sin \left( \frac{ \pi }{2} \right) = 1  $$

Comment: This is like the legit proof, lol

Answer (score 2):

$$sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1                      $$

Comment: $sin$ is continous everywhere